# What is the best way to load my own xhtml template in Codeigniter?

Tags: templates, codeigniter, xhtml

I'm new in Codeigniter, and I wonder how can I load my own XHTML template to be used, I was working on CakePHP earlier and it was pretty easy to add own template in Cake, but I switched to the Codeigniter, since I've read it's a lot better and has a 'better future'. I was searching on wiki, but tutorials there was providing not enough information for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put public folders in root directory,

```
index.php
application/
system/
images/
js/
css/
```

now include js like this: `<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>`

for css: `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

and for images: `<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/1.jpg" />`

the fastest and simplest way of display page, is as follows:
in controller:

```
$data['body'] = "welcome";
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

now create page.php inside the view folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"> 
<head> 
    <title>Template codeigniter</title> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div> 
        <?=$body?>
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div>Footer</div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: also enable url helper to use `base_url()` from application/config/autoload.php,..........line no:67 $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 1):

Loading templates is best described in the CI doc regarding templates.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data['val1'] = 'some string';
$data['val2'] = 2012;

$this->load->view('my_xhtml', $data);
```

Now, in your template, you will have PHP vars of $val1 & $val2 you can use in dynamic elements of your html.

Comment: Aight, thanks but where I need to paste my template files & images?

Comment: You can put your images in your site root. /images as for your template files, I typically create a templates directory in my views directory and refer to them as $this->load->view('templates/my_xhtml', $data);